# what is a .kendobutton() method in jquery and how to unbind and bind the 'click' event for this button?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I want to override click event of this button and write another function for it, how can I do this?

This function is written inside a partial view(.cshtml) in mvc. On click of the button, a partial view opens and shows a table containing data. Since I want to filter out the data shown, I have to override this function in another .js file as I cannot change this code.

Code:

```
<script>
$("#association-search-popup").kendoButton({
    enable: true,
    click: function (e) {
        var lookupEntityName = this.element.attr("data_lookupentityName");
        var lookupPropertyMetadata = this.element.attr("data_keypropertymetadata");
        var lookupAttribute = lookupEntityName;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Search/AssociationLookup",
            data: {"lookupEntityName": lookupEntityName},
            success: function (data) {
                var lookup_popup = $("#lookup_popup_content");
                lookup_popup.html("");
                lookup_popup.html(data);

                $('.searchbar-toggle').click(function (e) {
                    toggleFilterPane();
                    if ($("#divButtons").hasClass("search-popup-btn_expand")) {
                        $("#divButtons").removeClass("search-popup-btn_expand");
                        $("#divButtons").addClass("search-popup-btm_collapse");
                    } else if ($("#divButtons").hasClass("search-popup-btm_collapse")) {
                        $("#divButtons").removeClass("search-popup-btm_collapse");
                        $("#divButtons").addClass("search-popup-btn_expand");
                    }
                });

                $("#btnSelectItem").attr("search-lookup-type", "inheritance");

                ifPopup("lookup_popup");
            },
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind the current click function then bind a new one.

```
var button = $("#association-search-popup").getKendoButton();
button.unbind("click");
button.bind("click", function() {
    //new logic
});
```

Example: [Unbind click event](https://dojo.telerik.com/UnEmuput)

Comment: I am getting an error here.
Cannot read property 'unbind' of undefined at second line.

Comment: First line should be called after button initialization, and a script that contains `$("#association-search-popup").getKendoButton();` should be called after upper one.